# В каких случаях буква "Г" произносится как "Х"

Tags: фонетика

Возьмём три слова - "Бог", "Мягкий" и "Сапог". 
У слов "Бог" и "Мягкий" **г** произносится как **х**.
А у слова "Сапог" **г** произносится как **к**, хотя **г**, как и в слове "Бог" стоит в конце и перед буквой **о**.

Есть ли правило по произношению буквы **г** в русском языке?

Comment: А как еще можно произнести "мягкий" и "легкий"? У нас три заднеязычных звука  — Г, К, Х.  Звук Г перед глухим К (и на конце слова) оглушается по общим правилам и произносится как парный К, Тогда нужно произносить удвоенный звук К, который будет звучать как обычный К — "мякий". Такой вариант не подойдет, поэтому используется фрикативный звук Х из этой группы.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то нет, произносится как пишется. Однако разговорная речь и диалекты всегда отличаются от литературной нормы, и тут кто во что горазд. Кстати, "г" в боге подтверждается не только нашим написанием, но и, например, персидским, у которого это слово когда-то тоже было (отсюда Багдад, кстати. Данный богом). Другое дело, что буква может обозначать любой звук при желании, просто кириллице повезло и чаще чем нет её буквы совпадают со звучанием в том или ином языке.

Comment: А в орфоэпический словарь заглянуть –http://slovana.ru/slovari/reznichenko/orfoepicheskij-slovar-reznichenko_0068.htm

Answer (score 0):

По нормам орфоэпии в отдельных словах согласный [г] произносится как [х]: ***лёгкий, мягкий.*** Формы косвенных падежей, а также производные: ***мягкотелый, легковесный, налегке, мягче, легче, смягчить, облегчить, мягчайший, легчайший.*** В слове ***Бог*** на месте [г] идёт произношение согласного звука [х].

[источник](http://www.gramota.ru/book/village/map14.html#:%7E:text=%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%20%5B%CE%B3%5D%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE,%2C%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.)

[источник](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%B3%20%D1%87%D0%BC%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%85&oq=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%B3%20%D1%87%D0%BC%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%85&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIJCAEQIRgKGKABMgoIAhAhGBYYHRgeMgwIAxAhGA8YFhgdGB4yDAgEECEYDxgWGB0YHjIMCAUQIRgPGBYYHRgeMgwIBhAhGA8YFhgdGB4yDAgHECEYDxgWGB0YHjIMCAgQIRgPGBYYHRgeMgwICRAhGA8YFhgdGB7SAQo0MDA1M2owajE1qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

---

Отдельно о сапоге. С лингвистического форума:

[У меня в школе была непрекращающаяся война с учителем русского, которая тоже откуда-то из Ставрополья или из Краснодарского края была. Из-за фонетического разбора, ага. ЮХ, сапоХ, пироХ и т. п.](https://forum.materinstvo.ru/index.php?showtopic=1413054&st=880)